# how to optimize this layout?

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I have this xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nektaText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="example text will not be used" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/horilinee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/horiline" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:text="أرسل"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/commenttext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="اكتب التعليق هنا"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            </TableRow>

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/horilineee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/horiline" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/horiline"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/horiline" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/block"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/block" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbdown"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbup" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharetext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="شارك"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blocktext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="إبلاغ إساءة"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dislikenumber"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likenumber"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#00FF00"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but it doesn't seems to be working as I want it to be. I need it like the following figure:

[image: figure]

The problem with my code is the list view I can't stretch it to the bottom before the tablelayout. The other problem comes if the textview at the top is too long, it appears under the tablelayout and it's visible.

Also the tablelayout at the bottom shifted up when the keyboard is visible, I don't want this to happen.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: If you really want a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` you have to define it's height manually to scroll the whole layout. Otherwise `ScrollView` will not work, as `ListView` has it's own Scroller.

Comment: I tried to do that but the problem comes in the screen sizes. @Shaiful

Comment: from what i know, we cannot design with a listview inside scrollview. only one view with the scrolling ability can be used. wrap the listview in linear layout or relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

Have a single [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in your layout. You can add other views(as shown in your diagram) as headers to the list view using [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) method. This way you will get the Scrolling effect as you desired.

Comment: That is the correct answer. I know because I was going to answer it myself the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support. I came up with a better solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nektaText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="example text will not be used"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10pt" />
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/horilinee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/horiline" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="أرسل" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/commenttext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="اكتب التعليق هنا"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/horilineee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/horiline" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/horiline"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/horiline" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/block"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/block" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbdown"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbup" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharetext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="شارك"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blocktext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="إبلاغ إساءة"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dislikenumber"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likenumber"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#00FF00"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

ScrollView needs to declare :

```
android:layout_above="@+id/Layout1"
```

Layout1 is the layout that host tableLayout1

But you will have some issues with ListView into scrollView

Answer (score -1):

As there are only two Layout in your `RelativeLayout`, use `LinearLayout`. This will solve the overlap problem. Set the weight of `ScrollView` to keep the `TableLayout` at bottom.

The keyboard shift the Bottom table layout because it's mode is set to `Resize`. You will usually control this behavior through the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute on each  definition in your AndroidManifest.xml. Set the value of this to `adjustPan`.